# dplyr mutate stringr str_detect with multiple conditional arguments and corresponding output

Tags: r, if-statement, stringr, dplyr

I would like to mutate a string differently, depending on the format.  This example has 2 formats based on inclusion of certain punctuation.  Each element of the vector contains specific words uniquely associated with the format.

I have tried multiple approaches with ifelse and casewhen but not getting the desired results, which is to "keep" the last part of the string.

I am trying to use easy verbs and am not proficient in grex.  Open to any suggestions for an efficient general method.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(KPI = c("xxxxx.x...Alpha...Keep.1",
                     "xxxxx.x...Alpha..Keep.2",
                     "Bravo...Keep3",
                     "Bravo...Keep4",
                     "xxxxx...Charlie...Keep.5",
                     "xxxxx...Charlie...Keep.6"))

dot3dot3split <- function(x) strsplit(x,  "..." , fixed = TRUE)[[1]][3]
dot3dot3split("xxxxx.x...Alpha...Keep.1") # returns as expected
"Keep.1"

dot3split <- function(x) strsplit(x,  "..." , fixed = TRUE)[[1]][2]
dot3split("Bravo...Keep3") # returns as expected
"Keep3"

df1 <- df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
        mutate(KPI.v2 = ifelse(str_detect(KPI, paste(c("Alpha", "Charlie"), collapse = '|')), dot3dot3split(KPI), 
                               ifelse(str_detect(KPI, "Bravo"), dot3split(KPI), KPI))) # not working as expected
```

df1$KPI.v2
    "Keep.1" "Keep.1" "Alpha"  "Alpha"  "Keep.1" "Keep.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions you designed (`dot3dot3split` and `dot3split`) are not able to vectorize the operation. For example, if there are more than one elements, only the first one is returned. That may cause some problems.

```
dot3dot3split(c("xxxxx.x...Alpha...Keep.1", "xxxxx.x...Alpha..Keep.2"))
# [1] "Keep.1"
```

Since you are using [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr), I suggest that you can use `str_extract` to extract the string you want, without using `ifelse` or functions that can do vectorized operation.

```
df <- data.frame(KPI = c("xxxxx.x...Alpha...apples",
                         "xxxxx.x...Alpha..bananas",
                         "Bravo...oranges",
                         "Bravo...grapes",
                         "xxxxx...Charlie...cherries",
                         "xxxxx...Charlie...guavas"))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(KPI.v2 = str_extract(KPI, "[A-Za-z]*$"))
df1
#                          KPI   KPI.v2
# 1   xxxxx.x...Alpha...apples   apples
# 2   xxxxx.x...Alpha..bananas  bananas
# 3            Bravo...oranges  oranges
# 4             Bravo...grapes   grapes
# 5 xxxxx...Charlie...cherries cherries
# 6   xxxxx...Charlie...guavas   guavas
```

Comment: But I don't want to detect Keep, but rather Alpha Bravo and Charlie, and then Keep.  The problem I've had here is that there are different formats in the strong, but element of the vector contains specific words uniquely associated with each format.

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse Unclear to me what do you want. Please share your desired output.

Comment: i'm sorry, I was not clear.  In my example, the "Keep" component could be different for each record. So Keep.1 could be apples, Keep.2 "bananas", Keep.3 "Oranges" (I should have used that in my example, but used "Keep" to call out the portion I want to keep. I can rewrite the request this way if  that would be better.  But, as you can see in my original attempt, I searched for (str_detect) Alpha or Bravo or Charlie portion of the string in order to extract corresponding portion of the string that is desired.  I hope this helps clarify, and appreciate your time and interest in helping me.

Comment: I need to base the logic on Alpha, Bravo, Charlie because there are far fewer # of these factors to search for than there are "keep" elements

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse Please see my update. I have created an example data frame based on your description and updated my regex code.

Comment: you nailed it, thank you very much!  This is going to help my efficiency greatly.  I wish I could throw you some more of my rep points. I need to learn regex somehow.

Comment: You're welcome. I changed the regex once again to make it more concise. Here is a link I think could be useful to learn regex in R (http://uc-r.github.io/regex).